# how to plot network with different edge types on R?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-visualization

I want to plot a directed weighted  network in which I could show stock transactions between participants.  I'm not sure if we can add a 3rd columne ("TYPE") in a edgelist in the igraph R package.  If so, can we differentiate the edges based on the purchased stock? 
e.g. Apple : blue edge, google : red edge, Pfizer: orange edge.

Edgelist

```
FROM TO VALUE TYPE
A    B  100   Apple
B    C  50    Pfizer
C    D  80    Apple
A    E  70    Google

    require(igraph)
test<-as.matrix(edge_list_test)
test[,1]<-as.character(test[,1])
test[,2]<-as.character(test[,2])
test[,4]<-as.character(test[,4])
g<-graph.edgelist(test[,1:2], directed=TRUE)
V(g)$size=degree(g)
E(g)$type=as.character(test[,4])
E(g)$weight=as.numeric(test[,3])
    plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, edge.width=E(g)$weight, vertex.color=V(g)$type, vertex.label.dist=0.5)][1]][1]
```

Why are the edges gray and can't see different colors on the edges based on the "TYPE"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code as provided, I get ridiculously big arrows so I will adjust `edge.width`.  Nothing in your plot statement sets the edge color. You need to do that explicitly with the `edge.color` parameter.

```
CR = rainbow(length(unique(edge_list_test$TYPE)))
plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, 
    edge.width=E(g)$weight/15, vertex.color=V(g)$type, 
    vertex.label.dist=0.5, edge.color=CR[edge_list_test$TYPE])
legend("topleft", legend=levels(edge_list_test$TYPE), lwd=2, col=CR)
```

[image: Colored Arrows]

I used `edge_list_test$TYPE` to select the edge color instead of `E(g)$type` because `edge_list_test$TYPE` is a factor and `E(g)$type` is just a string.

Comment: Actually, I'd like different edge colors, based on the "type". For instance, a trade involving Apple stock should have a blue edge. 
What does "rgb" stands for ?  I guess I would need to write 'edge.color=rgb(CR(E(g)$type))'  instead?

Comment: I misunderstood. Answer has been adjusted to base arrow color on TYPE.